# Is it possible to target a single build agent for an agent but not specify which agent?

Tags: msbuild

We have two build agents that runs on the same server serving four projects that are under development as well as under support.

We want the projects to be build as fast as possible i.e. we don't want to reserv a specific agent for each project since that would likely put some builds in a queue even though another agent is available.

Since we have both unit and integrationstests that targets a databas locally installed on the buildserver we need to have some way of making sure that several checkins for the same project isn't run in parallell on different build agents since that would make collisions in the tests regarding the database.

So how can we setup the build so that a specific project only will trigger a build if no other build for the project currently is running and otherwise place the build in a queue to be started after the previous build for that project is completed?

Some builds take up to an hour to complete so its not really feasible to make the developers remember to trigger a new build.

The following scenario may help to understand the question:

1. Checkin for project A happens which trigger a build on Build agent 1
2. Checkin for project B happens which trigger a build on Build agent 2
3. Another checkin happens for project A which is the put in queue
4. Build of project B completes
5. Second checkin for project A is given to Build agent 2 (triggers collisions in integrationstests)

What we want is instead the following

1. Checkin for project A happens which trigger a build on Build agent 1
2. Checkin for project B happens which trigger a build on Build agent 2
3. Another checkin happens for project A which is the put in queue
4. Build of project B completes
5. Since build is still active for project A the second checkin is not yet started
6. Build of project A completes
7. New build for project A starts on either build agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "Rolling Builds" rather than CI builds, if a build is currently active a new build of the same type will not start until the 1st build completes. I'm not sure if it's 100% what you want, but it's pretty close.

A rolling build will accumulate checkins so if there are 20 checkins whist the 1st build is running then all 20 chekins will be included in the second build. It will not queue 20 builds.

Comment: So if I create a rolling build for one particulare build there will only ever be one build for that definition active at the same time? Even if the build takes, say 30 minutes, and the rolling build is set to every other minute? If so this is the solution I'm after

Comment: That's correct, rolling builds "stack". If you have a rolling build configured (no time limit set) then only one will run, the next build will be triggered as soon as the first build finishes. If you have a rolling build set with a 30 minute time limit and your first build takes 20 minutes the second build will be triggered 10 minutes after the first finishes. Finally if you have a rolling build set with a 30 minute time limit and your first build takes 40 minutes, the second build will be triggered when the first build finishes

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to add 2 more agents to that server, so you have one agent per project.  Then use the Build Agent tags (or build agent names) to tie each projects build definition to the agent dedicated to it.

Comment: I guess that is the simplest solution so if nobody else comes up with anything else that will be the solution we use.